Unresolved reference: expo
I tried to install Expo both automatically and manually. When I installed it automatically, it gave import and top declaration errors in my MainActivity.kt file. When I tried to install it manually, when I added this line "import expo.modules.ReactActivityDelegateWrapper", I got the "Unresolved reference: expo" error. When I did the same project on my friend's computer by following the same steps, I did not receive any errors and the project worked. As far as I understand, I thought there might be version problems on my computer and I installed whatever versions were on my friend's computer, but I still got the same error. When I researched on the internet, I did not find anyone getting this error and expo When I asked about the error on 's discord server, no one answered, so I'm waiting for your help here, thank you.
C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring> yarn run aos:prod
yarn run v1.22.22
$ SET ENVFILE=.env.production && react-native run-android --mode=productionDebug --appIdSuffix=production
warn Package rn-fetch-blob contains invalid configuration: "dependency.hooks" is not allowed. Please verify it's properly linked using "npx react-native config" command and contact the package maintainers about this.
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env.production 

> Configure project :notifee_react-native
:notifee_react-native @notifee/react-native found at C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\@notifee\react-native
:notifee_react-native package.json found at C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\@notifee\react-native\package.json
:notifee_react-native:version set from package.json: 7.8.2 (7,8,2 - 7008002)
:notifee_react-native:android.compileSdk using custom value: 34
:notifee_react-native:android.targetSdk using custom value: 34
:notifee_react-native:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:notifee_react-native:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 32.8.1
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 21.0.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 19.2.2 (19,2,2 - 19002002)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 34
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 34
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_database
:react-native-firebase_database package.json found at C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\database\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_database:firebase.bom using default value: 32.8.1
:react-native-firebase_database package.json found at C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\database\package.json
:react-native-firebase_database:version set from package.json: 19.2.2 (19,2,2 - 19002002)
:react-native-firebase_database:android.compileSdk using custom value: 34
:react-native-firebase_database:android.targetSdk using custom value: 34
:react-native-firebase_database:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_database:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_messaging
:react-native-firebase_messaging package.json found at C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\messaging\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_messaging:firebase.bom using default value: 32.8.1
:react-native-firebase_messaging package.json found at C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\messaging\package.json
:react-native-firebase_messaging:version set from package.json: 19.2.2 (19,2,2 - 19002002)
:react-native-firebase_messaging:android.compileSdk using custom value: 34
:react-native-firebase_messaging:android.targetSdk using custom value: 34
:react-native-firebase_messaging:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_messaging:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.1.1
Gradle: 8.3

> Configure project :react-native-vision-camera
[VisionCamera] Thank you for using VisionCamera ??
[VisionCamera] node_modules found at C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring\node_modules
[VisionCamera] VisionCamera_enableFrameProcessors is set to true!
[VisionCamera] react-native-worklets-core not found, Frame Processors are disabled!
[VisionCamera] VisionCamera_enableCodeScanner is set to true!
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (33.0.0) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (33.0.1) for Android Gradle Plugin 8.1.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 33.0.1 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 33 in C:\Users\dberk\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 33 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision 3)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision 3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 33 in C:\Users\dberk\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33
"Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision 3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision 3)" finished.

> Task :app:compileProductionDebugKotlin FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
453 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 446 up-to-date
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
e: file:///C:/Users/dberk/GitHub/tebfaktoring/android/app/src/main/java/com/tebfaktoring/MainActivity.kt:2:8 Unresolved reference: expo                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileProductionDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 27s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installProductionDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
e: file:///C:/Users/dberk/GitHub/tebfaktoring/android/app/src/main/java/com/tebfaktoring/MainActivity.kt:2:8 Unresolved reference: expo FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileProductionDebugKotlin'. > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction > Compilation error. See log for more details * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 27s.     
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
PS C:\Users\dberk\GitHub\tebfaktoring>

